# Какой компонент использовать?

Tags: delphi-11-alexandria

Надо написать новую (предыдущая не устраивает) программку для правки/редактирования/перевода текста. Пример текста:

<RHINOSTRING_STATUSBAR_MESSAGE English="Could not convert Rhino loop." Localized="Could not convert Rhino loop." ID="IDS_COULD_NOT_CONVERT_LOOP"/>

Это не xml и не html. В файле (пока) до 45000 строк. Надо сделать подсветку строк, тегов, линейки, номера строк и установку меток на номере строк. Memo и RichEdit (~15 секунд) долго грузят файл, а работа а автоматическом режиме, например, поиск и замена на старом компьютере могла длиться около 20 минут.

Какой компонент лучше использовать в Delphi 7 и RAD Studio 11.3?